# Comparing 3 lists answering true if letter or value is in each list. Python 3

Tags: python

I am trying to use Python to compare 3 strings/lists, find whether there is a matching letter or number in each sequence and to return the result true or false.

For example, if the 3 sequences are:

`y, x
x, 4, e
a, e, x, 3, w.`

It would return 'true' as there is a 'x' in each sequence.

However, if the sequence is:

```
a, b, c
c, d, e
e, f, g, h.
```

It will return 'false' as there is not a letter c in each of the three sequences..

So far I have come up with the following:

```
print("INPUT:")
input_A = input( "sequence A: " ) 
input_B = input( "sequence B: " )
input_C = input( "sequence C: " )

#converting all 3 to lists
input_list_A = input_A.split("," )
input_list_B = input_B.split("," )
input_list_C = input_C.split("," )

match = input_list_A==input_list_B==input_list_C
print(match)
```

The problem with the current code is that it checks whether the whole sequence is the same and not cross matching between commas with other sequences. Since I am new to code I do not understand how to write this in Python and would appreciate if someone could lead me to the right direction.

Comment: What do you think the outcome of `list1 == list2` is?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem False, as if you follow the first example I have given. y, x does not match c, d, e. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `==` will not achieve what you want. You can do it with set intersection . Try below code 
And you need to do error handling. This code works only when input sequence has `,` in it

```
print("INPUT:")
input_A = input( "sequence A: " ) 
input_B = input( "sequence B: " )
input_C = input( "sequence C: " )

#converting all 3 to lists
input_list_A = input_A.split("," )
input_list_B = input_B.split("," )
input_list_C = input_C.split("," )

if set(input_list_A).intersection(set(input_list_B)):
    if set(input_list_A).intersection(set(input_list_C)):
        print ("matched")
    else:
        print ("not matched")
else:
    print ("not matched")

#print(match)
```

Comment: You can do a simple `set(input_list_A) & set(input_list_B) & set(input_list_C)` to do all the intersections in the same line. https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects

Answer (score 0):

The class set is great for this kind of stuff, check out the [documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set) Use sets instead of lists, and use the method ´intersection()´.
ex:

```
a = {"y", "x"}
b = {"x", 4, "e"}
c = {"a", "e", "x", 3, "w"}

d = a.intersection(b)
print(d.intersection(c))
```